# SQL Server: How to get JSON in one query?

Tags: json, sql-server

I have 2 queries return json

```
    select * from
    (
        SELECT Person.id, Person.name as label, 'Person' as 'group', Person.id as value
        FROM Person, likes, Restaurant
        WHERE MATCH (Person-(likes)->Restaurant)
    ) 
    t FOR JSON PATH,
    ROOT('nodes')

--- edges
    SELECT pe.id as 'from',re.id as 'to', 
    (cast(pe.id as nvarchar(12))+N'=>'+cast(re.id as nvarchar(12))) as label,
    'to' as arrows
    FROM person pe, likes li, restaurant re
    where match(pe-(li)->re)
    FOR JSON PATH,ROOT('edges')
```

They return 2 json results

```
"nodes": [
{"id":1,"label":"John","group":"Person","value":1},
{"id":2,"label":"Mary","group":"Person","value":2},
{"id":3,"label":"Alice","group":"Person","value":3},
]}
{"edges":[
{"from":1,"to":1,"label":"1=>1","arrows":"to"},
{"from":2,"to":2,"label":"2=2","arrows":"to"},
]}
```

I'd like to wrap this to a function which returns json.
How to receive the result with additional level like this in one query:

```
{
"name": "Nodes", --<-- the new one!
"nodes": [
{"id":1,"label":"John","group":"Person","value":1},
{"id":2,"label":"Mary","group":"Person","value":2},
{"id":3,"label":"Alice","group":"Person","value":3},
]}
{"edges":[
{"from":1,"to":1,"label":"1=>1","arrows":"to"},
{"from":2,"to":2,"label":"2=2","arrows":"to"},
]}
```

Comment: do you want the `json` from two queries in one object or you want  two `json` from one query?

Comment: I need the final json from 2 queries (above) and + additional "name": "Nodes"

Comment: means you need all the result in one object

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I have made it via select into nvarchar